# Custom GROUP BY in Jasper Report

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am trying to make a MySQL-backed Jasper Report have a certain GROUP BY in the query expression.  I am able to switch between two different columns using a parameter:

```
SELECT id, city, state, zip, value1, value2, value3, IF($P{consolidate_zip}, zip, city) AS groupField
FROM table1
GROUP BY groupField
```

In this case, however, I need to switch between multiple columns or a single column.

```
SELECT id, city, state, zip, value1, value2, value3, IF($P{consolidate_loc}, "city, state, zip", city) AS groupField
FROM table1
GROUP BY groupField
```

I'm trying to fit this into an existing report generator, so I am limited to the SQL expression, properties, and parameters.

Is there a way to utilize report properties, or format the expression to allow this type of grouping to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be pretty, but you can concatenate them together:

```
SELECT id, city, state, zip, value1, value2, value3,
       IF($P{consolidate_loc}, concat(city, ', ', state, ' ', zip), city) AS groupField
FROM table1
GROUP BY groupField;
```

You have all the fields in the `select` already, so you can just put the expression in the `group by`:

```
SELECT id, city, state, zip, value1, value2, value3
FROM table1
GROUP BY IF($P{consolidate_loc}, concat(city, ', ', state, ' ', zip), city)
```

If any of the values might be `NULL`, you would need to replace them (preferably with `coalesce()`.